# Do I need a model catalog or feature store if experiments are being tracked?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Here are some uses I've found for each case:

- The model catalog lets you document the use case, the machine learning framework that was used to train the model, the version of that framework, and the algorithm used along with its hyperparameters.- [Link](https://blogs.oracle.com/ai-and-datascience/post/reproduce-and-audit-your-models-easily-with-a-model-catalog#:%7E:text=The%20model%20catalog%20lets%20you,used%20along%20with%20its%20hyperparameters.)
- A feature store is a tool for storing commonly used features. When data scientists develop features for a machine learning model, those features can be added to the feature store. This makes those features available for reuse. - [Link](https://www.phdata.io/blog/what-is-a-feature-store/#:%7E:text=A%20feature%20store%20is%20a,those%20features%20available%20for%20reuse.&text=Transforms%20raw%20data%20into%20feature%20values%20by%20executing%20data%20pipelines.)
- Experiment tracking is the process of saving all experiment-related information that you care about for every experiment you run. - [Link](https://neptune.ai/blog/best-ml-experiment-tracking-tools#:%7E:text=In%20machine%20learning%2C%20experiment%20tracking,%2C%20or%20self%2Dbuilt%20platforms.)

From my understanding, good experiment tracking would track models (thus documenting the use case) and training data (thus storing the features). What's the point of the model catalog and feature store then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature store is primarily for reusability. Commonly used features can be used directly from the feature store without the need for re-engineering. This is different than the data used in experiment tracking, which stores the data and features explicitly *used* in that experiment. The saved features can be pointers to feature store.

The model catalog described in Oracle's website is for reproducibility and source of a deployed model. But, it does not save all the experiment-related information, tuning etc. like an experiment tracking process.

Comment: But with different platforms (i.e. Comet.ml, W&B, etc) it's possible to log the experiments and artifacts. Wouldn't that mean creating an entire catalog for models and features is pointless?

Comment: The feature store is fundamentally different. Certain experiments can use certain parts of the data, bu the feature store is there for all the data, to increase efficiency of data scientists. It prevents the same features being reengineered from raw data. Experiment tracking is conceptually different than model store. But, platforms that provide this service can easily extend its capabilities by including it. I don't know if the mentioned platforms do that or not.